# Contact form using AJAX and PHP not sending

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, contacts, contact-form

I have a contact form that won't send whatsoever. I'm using PHP with AJAX and including validator.js also. I know that the problem is not with validator.js but its most likely in the AJAX or PHP files.

The code for sending the form can be found here:

PHP - http://codepad.org/05lMHmfa

```
<?php

// configure
$from = 'Demo contact form <domain email>'; 
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <personal email>';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// sending

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}

?>
```

AJAX - http://codepad.org/gTX0CyFA

```
$(function () {

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

..and the HTML `

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
    <form>
        <p>txt
            </p>
        <hr>
        <p> txt </p>
        <hr>
        <p>Are you ready to find out what Docs24 can do for you? </p>
</div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

                    <div class="messages"></div>

                    <div class="controls">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required"
                                        data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required"
                                        data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required"
                                        data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
                                    <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required"
                                        data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
                            </div>              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>`
```

If someone could point me in the right direction with this it would be much appreciated. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Error in the browser console perhaps?

Comment: Nothing related to any of the files in question.

Comment: And did you know that other Javascript errors could quit easily cause the rest of your Javascript to not be called too? Fix your errors, then see what happens.

Comment: You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are not debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck post **only the relevant code** with a concise description of your problem. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: Open the developer console and see if the AJAX request sends correctly.